# Remote Python Environment for Sublime

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

For various purposes one might need to hook up a remote python interpreter.

1. How can I access anaconda/bin from an sshfs mounted folder, all tries yielded access denied since the interpreter and python file are on different machines.
2. There is a solution of hosting a server on the remote machine to access the remote conda install, this is not an option.
3. Alternatively one could install the same environment locally, how would one keep them in sync?

The main idea is to get [anaconda sublime](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) functionality on the local machine. Running/managing a python project can easily be done through ssh.

Edit: I am aware of the various remote/on_server editing options, (vim, emacs ...) but we have to stick to sublime.

Note: I do not have sudo privileges on this server.

Comment: Have you found any solution for your problem? If so, please post it here. I am also facing the same issue

Comment: switched to visual studio code ... works a charm on linux